# Invalid object name '#subodh'

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```
Alter Procedure sp_Member(
@comcode int = 0,
@SubComCode int = 0
)
as
begin
set nocount on
If @comcode= 0
begin
select
(select sum(amount)    
    from tbcoudet 
    where memcode=tbm.memcode and expyear=(select max(expyear) from tbexpyear) 
    and exists(select itemcode 
            from tbitem 
            where comcode=@comcode and 
                  SubComCode=@SubComCode and
                  itemcode=tbcoudet.itemcode
            )
    group by memcode,expyear
)'TurnOver'
, *  into #subodh from tbmember tbm where can_flag='N' 
end
If @SubComCode= 0
begin
Insert into #subodh
select
(select sum(amount)    
    from tbcoudet 
    where memcode=tbm.memcode and expyear=(select max(expyear) from tbexpyear) 
    and exists(select itemcode 
            from tbitem 
            where comcode=@comcode and 
                  itemcode=tbcoudet.itemcode
            )
    group by memcode,expyear
)'TurnOver'
, *  from tbmember tbm where can_flag='N'
end

select top 10 * from #subodh where TurnOver is not null order by TurnOver desc

end
```

My problem is that when i am going to execute `EXEC sp_Member @comcode='1',@subcomcode='1'` OR `select top 10 * from #subodh where TurnOver is not null order by TurnOver`  these query then i geting error "Invalid object name '#subodh'." please tell me why i am geting this error and how can i solve it...please

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because the table *might* not be created with `insert into` statement. This happens because the `select` *might* not give any results. So the compiler doesn't allow this code because in the future in can give an error.

Instead of making an `insert into`, `create` the `table #subodh` first (and `drop` it at the end) and you won't get that problem.